# Como saber se o visitante é o Google bot, ou Facebook bot

Tags: php, facebook, google, boot

Tem alguma forma, via PHP, de saber se quem está visitando minha página é o Google bot e Facebook bot?

Answer (score 1):

## Google

```
if (strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "googlebot")) {
    // Provavelmente proveio do google.
    // Aqui você implementa as suas firulas.
}
```

## Facebook:

```
if (
    strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "facebookexternalhit/") !== false ||          
    strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Facebot") !== false
) {
    // Provavelmente proveio do facebook.
    // Aqui você implementa as suas firulas.
}
```

**Nota:**
Esteja ciente de que é fácil manipular o HTTP_USER_AGENT. Qualquer pessoa pode criar um script que se auto identifique como **googlebot**, por exemplo. Portanto, não confie 100% nesse parâmetro.

Para garantir maior integridade terá que fazer verificações de DNS reverso, origem do IP, etc.

Comment: +1, mas uma pequena observação: nos dois casos eu usaria o `stripos`, que é case-insensitive. Além disso, `strstr` é menos eficiente, o próprio manual do PHP recomenda usar `strpos` se for só pra saber se a string está contida.

Comment: Se for para simples contagem de visitas, utilize o google analytics. Ele filtra e lista somente visitas válidas.

Comment: @AndreCardoso tem mais informações de como usar o mesmo?

Comment: @LuizaCH, é bem simples. Basta realizar o cadastro no Google Analytics, adicionar um novo site (informar os dados necessários como tipo do site e tudo mais), confirmar a adesão (termos de uso) e o Google vai gerar um código para ser adicionado no site, é bem simples, o código vem pronto, basta adicionar no rodapé da página. Aí depois é só acompanhar os acessos pelo painel: http://www.andrebian.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Screenshot-from-2016-03-15-223530.png